# Convert from timestamp (Epoch time) to Proper Pandas DateTime colimn

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp

Trying to convert a column from timestamps to datetime, desired result printed last.
The source is a Unix epoch timestamp. I can convert a single value, but am not able to do it on a full column of data.
Thank you!!

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
thd = pd.DataFrame(data=data["candles"])
data={'candles': [{'open': 1417.5,
   'high': 1417.52,
   'low': 1416.95,
   'close': 1416.95,
   'volume': 508,
   'datetime': 1590758940},
  {'open': 1416.95,
   'high': 1420.18,
   'low': 1415.06,
   'close': 1416.64,
   'volume': 32934,
   'datetime': 1590759000},]
}

thd["Time"]=pd.to_datetime(thd["datetime"])
display(thd)
datetime.fromtimestamp(1590759060) #<---this is the result I want to get on dataframe
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use apply on a column to execute this function for each value in a column

```
thd['datetime'].apply(datetime.fromtimestamp)
```

Full code

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

data={'candles': [{'open': 1417.5,
'high': 1417.52,
'low': 1416.95,
'close': 1416.95,
'volume': 508,
'datetime': 1590758940},
{'open': 1416.95,
'high': 1420.18,
'low': 1415.06,
'close': 1416.64,
'volume': 32934,
'datetime': 1590759000},]
}

thd = pd.DataFrame(data=data["candles"])

thd['datetime_converted'] = thd['datetime'].apply(datetime.fromtimestamp)

thd
```

Result

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with `unit='s'`:

```
In [731]: thd['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(thd['datetime'], unit='s') 

In [732]: thd                                                          
Out[732]: 
      open     high      low    close  volume            datetime
0 1,417.50 1,417.52 1,416.95 1,416.95     508 2020-05-29 13:29:00
1 1,416.95 1,420.18 1,415.06 1,416.64   32934 2020-05-29 13:30:00
```